# R/ggplot2: smooth on entire dataset while enforcing a ylim cap

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, smoothing

### UPDATE:  I found the answer... included it below.

I have a dataset that contains the following variables and similar values:

```
COBSDATE,   CITY, RESPONSE_TIME
2011-11-23  A     1.1
2011-11-23  A     1.5
2011-11-23  A     1.2
2011-11-23  B     2.3
2011-11-23  B     2.1
2011-11-23  B     1.8
2011-11-23  C     1.4
2011-11-23  C     6.1
2011-11-23  A     3.1
2011-11-23  A     1.1
```

I have successfully created a graph that displays all of the response_time values and a smooth geometry to further describe some of the variation.

The challenge that I have is that I want a better view of the smoothed value, and one of the cities has frequent 'outliers'.  I can control this by adding ylim(0,p99) to the plot, but this then causes the smooth to only be calculated on the subset of data.

Is there a way to use all of this data for the smoothed plot and the only the subset for the jitter plot?

My code here (both are the same except for the `+ ylim(0,20)`:
truncated -

```
ggplot(dataRaw, aes(x=COBSDATE, y=RESPONSE_TIME)) + 
    geom_jitter(colour=alpha("#007DB1", 1/8)) + 
    geom_smooth(colour="gray30", fill=alpha("gray40",0.5)) + 
    ylim(0,20) + 
    facet_wrap(~CITY)
```

Whole data set -

```
ggplot(dataRaw, aes(x=COBSDATE, y=RESPONSE_TIME)) + 
    geom_jitter(colour=alpha("#007DB1", 1/8)) + 
    geom_smooth(colour="gray30", fill=alpha("gray40",0.5)) + 
    facet_wrap(~CITY)
```

Comment: Can you use `dput` to give us a subset of the data so we can plot this out?

Comment: Please don't put an answer in your question. There's a designated spot for answers just below! Put it as an answer and then after the waiting period is over, accept it! Answering your own question is perfectly ok here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you just want to "zoom in", you can use `coord_cartesian`:

```
ggplot(dataRaw, aes(x=COBSDATE, y=RESPONSE_TIME)) + 
  geom_jitter(colour=alpha("#007DB1", 1/8)) + 
  geom_smooth(colour="gray30", fill=alpha("gray40",0.5)) + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,20)) + 
  facet_wrap(~CITY)
```

If you want to use a subset of the data for the jitter geom, then override the data inheritance:

```
ggplot(dataRaw, aes(x=COBSDATE, y=RESPONSE_TIME)) + 
  geom_jitter(data=subset(dataRaw, RESPONSE_TIME>=0 & RESPONSE_TIME<=20), 
              colour=alpha("#007DB1", 1/8)) + 
  geom_smooth(colour="gray30", fill=alpha("gray40",0.5)) + 
  ylim(0,20) + 
  facet_wrap(~CITY)
```

Answer (score 5):

UPDATED ANSWER:So, I was looking for something completely different and stumbled upon the answer I needed.

Instead of `ylim(0,yMax)` One should use `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, yMax))`

It appears that `coord_cartesian` simply "zooms" the graph instead of truncating the data included.