# How to change ylim per facet with coord_cartesian in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505270/r-ggplot2-smooth-on-entire-dataset-while-enforcing-a-ylim-cap) describes how to change the y limits of a plot in ggplot.  Suppose I have a faceted plot with a different ylim for each facet, e.g.

```
facet_wrap(~some_facet, scales="free_y")
```

How can I change the y limits for each facet differently?

Comment: Do you need to increase the limits or decrease them? (There is no clean way to do this.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207419/r-how-do-i-use-coord-cartesian-on-facet-grid-with-free-ranging-axis might help

Comment: @joran My use case was trying to exclude any negative numbers, since I know all the counts are positive, but adding geom_smooth() using loess added massive error bars into the negative.

Comment: @user20650 Thanks for the ref. That may be the right thing, but I'm not going to reach into the grobs for now. I ended up just restricting the X axis so it didn't reach the point where the error bars go largely negative.